# How do you send mass emails using mysql details based on certain criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, database, email, phplist

I need to email my websites members easily based on certain criteria in the mysql database.

For example:

email all females that are over 25 years old (assuming these variables are stored in the database)

I have installed and looked at phplist which seems great but I can't work out how to
automatically add members to it when they sign up to my site and how to email based on criteria.

If theres a better way of doing it other than using something like phplist please let me know. I would like to be able to do this reasonably easily when sending out weekly emails.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to use phplist, or are you asking someone to write a custom application for you, or something else? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Could you not run a query on your MySQL database and then send emails to the accounts that come up?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) and the mailing options it provides.